# stretching clipping mask based on clipping mask dim photoshop cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask

what should I do if I want to stretch the clipping mask together with the masked layer based on clipping mask dimensions, in photoshop cs6? can I set the final dimensions using numbers? thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Would you mind showing an image, such as a screen shot which demonstrates what you are trying to achieve. It's quite difficult to understand from words alone. I'm having some difficulty imagining what stretching a clipping masked "based on clipping mask dimensions" would actually entail.  We like pictures here. Thanks.

Comment: ..... huh? ...........